# Can Sitecore 9.1 with JSS use VueJS 3

Tags: jss

We have a Sitecore 9.1 site which uses JSS 11.0.2 - the supported version for 9.1.

The node module `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue` (currently also 11.0.2) mentions in its devDependencies section `"vue": "^2.5.17"` which to me implies that it can use anything *upto but not including* version 3.0.0 of VueJS.

Is my understanding correct here?

If not, how would I go about upgrading to VueJS 3.3.4? Would upgrading Sitecore and then the JSS modules be the only supported way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: ***No***.

Looking at the `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue` package on npmjs.com (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue) reveals that from version 19 onwards it supported VueJS 3 and above.

This table, https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000576 indicates that Sitecore 10.2 or later is required for sitecore-jss-vue version 19.

So for:

| VueJS | Sitecore | JSS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.x | <= 10.1 | <= 18 |
| 3.x | >= 10.2 | >= 19 |

If you're not using JSS/Headless architecture, but are using Vue JS then you would not have any Sitecore dependencies preventing you from upgrading.